# Why is scanf() always waiting for input

Tags: c, scanf

I'm updating this with some examples on what's not working. The scanf keeps asking for some input that it shouldn't be asking for.

```
int n = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
double a[DIM][DIM];

do
{
    printf("Give the dimension n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
}while(n < 2 || n > DIM);

printf("n: %d\n", n);

printf("Give matrix A:\n");
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("Row %d:\n", i+1);
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        printf("\tCol %d: ",j+1);
        scanf("%lf", &a[i][j]);
    }
}
printf("Workin");
```

Input example:

```
Give the dimension n: 2
n: 2
Give matrix A:
Row 1:
    Col 1: 1.0
    Col 2: 2.0
Row 2:
    Col 1: 3.0
    Col 2: 4.0
```

Any idea on why this isn't working?
I'm just probably being stupid, ain't I?

Comment: what is the value of DIM?

Comment: for me it worked, so remains @saadtaame's question.

Comment: The value of DIM is 20.

Comment: should work fine, it must be that some other part is causing the loop or you are always scanning integers n that make it do so.

Comment: What is the input for `n` ?

Comment: @IgnasiSánchez what makes you think it's an inifinite loop?, there is nothing in your code that would inidicate that, unless `Give the dimension n: ` is printed infinite times, there will be no way to distinguish an infinite loop from `scanf()` waiting for input, i suggest you add a `printf()` line before `scanf()` to instruct the user to input the numbers.

Comment: #define DIM 20 As it should be.

Comment: Yeah... it could be that 'scanf()' is waiting for an input. In fact, I'm 99% sure of it. The issue is that I input the required variables, and it still won't work.

Comment: @IgnasiSánchez can you please post your input?

Comment: @IgnasiSánchez The scanf is expecting a double integer.

I agree with iharob. If you could tell us on what input this behaviour occurs, we may be able to help you.

Comment: Sure: `Give the dimension n: 2
n: 2
Give matrix A:
1
2
3
4
5
64
564614
`

Comment: And you can keep adding numbers on and on

Comment: I compiled your program. Stopped reading inputs right after it took 5. Should have taken just until 4....

Comment: @iharob Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: @kkaosninja I'm thinking....

Comment: @iharob I updated the post in order to clarify what's going on. If you will, you can take a look and it may clarify what's happening. I'm not really understading why this is happening, but surely you do. I'm pretty much a noob with C.

Comment: @IgnasiSánchez are you pressing enter after inputing the values?

Comment: Works fine for me, have you try to run it in debug to see what happens?

Comment: @TomerArazy I'm not really familiarized with the debugger in C. I'm working on it at the moment, trying to figure it out :P

Comment: ok - did you remember to include `stdio.h`?

Comment: It would've given me an error if I missed it, wouldn't it? (it's curiosity, I'm not being sassy). And yes, it's there.

Comment: There would be a warning, sadly. Not an error, the warning saying that `scanf()` as declared implicitly, the effect the compiler will pass all arguments as integers AFAIK. Though that never happened to me because I make compiler warnings as errors to avoid silly mistakes.

Comment: Well, i'm out of ideas. Have you tried kicking the computer really hard?

Comment: @TomerArazy yeah that might fix it, because i don't see another solution either :).

Comment: @TomerArazy I've tried to compile it in Ubuntu, W8, W7, two different computers and two different compilers. I'm working on the debugger to see if I can get something clear, but it doesn't seem like it.

Comment: @IgnasiSánchez the real problem is that it works for me except for the trailing `'\n'` that requires an extra number to be input, but it didn't stop waiting forever. So how can I help you if I can't reproduce the problem. Would it be ok to suggest an alternate method of solving this?

Comment: Sure, I'm open to every suggestion. Since you told me that you were going to add an answer I was waiting for it ^^.

Comment: @iharob Okay I fixed it. I don't know why, but switching again to W7 solved it. Anyways, I would really appreciate if you added the other method that you were talking about, since knowledge doesn't hurt anyone, doesn't it?

Comment: I didn't add another method, what i added was a function to eat what `scanf()` ignores. Please tell me what requirements you have to take input from the user, should it be valid if he enters `1 2 3 4 5 .. ` and then hit's enter? or should the user press enter after each number? or both?

Comment: @iharob I think both methods should work. At least, I've always used both, and I've never had any issue.

Comment: Well with `scanf()` they will both work for sure.

Comment: I declared `DIM` and assigned the value `20` to it, I compiled your code, and then I entered your example input `Give the dimension n: 2`
`Row 1:`
    `Col 1: 1.0`
    `Col 2: 2.0`
`Row 2:`
    `Col 1: 3.0`
    `Col 2: 4.0` and it **worked perfectly fine**, with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` ignores spaces, so try consuming them separately

```
void consumeSpaces()
{
    int chr;
    while ((chr = fgetc(stdin)) && (isspace(chr) != 0));
    ungetc(chr, stdin);
}

int main()
{
    int i, j, n;
    double a[DIM][DIM];

    do
    {
        printf("Give the dimension n: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while (n < 2 || n > DIM);


    printf("n: %d\n", n);
    printf("Give matrix A:\n");

    consumeSpaces();
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            consumeSpaces();
            scanf("%lf", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("a[%d][%d] -> %f\n", i, j, a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's an infinite loop? The code looks fine to me, but your double-loop will execute a lot of times.  For example if `n` is 19 your outer loop will execute 19 times, but your inner loop will execute 19 for each iteration of the outer loop for a total of 361 iterations.

Comment: 20*20 iterations will execute instantly.

Comment: No it won't.  The inside loop has a scanf which will wait for input from STDIN which is why I asked if the OP is sure it's an infinite loop.

Comment: your post just says it will execute lots of times and does not mention the scanf..it could be that he is reading from a file opened with freopen. just to be sure. so fix it

Comment: why would I mention the scanf? It's in the OPs code for everybody to see and given that the previous code performs a printf followed by a scanf it is very likely that the next scanf is reading from STDIN and waiting for human input

Answer (score -1):

I suggest the data you read from scanf is too short or a number is malformed. scanf will keep reading if it gets bad data until it gets good data, but in a way that's very confusing. Normally use fgets() and sscanf().

Comment: While this is very good advice, it doesn't look to me like an answer.

Comment: It's immediately obvious the for loops are not malformed but yet he gets an infinite loop. I think it's inside the scanf call.